# Firestore database infinite loop React Js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have my react js app linked to cloud Firestore and I'm trying to display the objects on my js file.

I have only 1 object in my Firestore but it keeps reading in a loop and i cant figure out why.

Code from explore.js (display objects from Firebase)

```
  const [nft,setNft]=useState([])
  const getNft= async()=>{
     const nft = await fs.collection('NFT').get();
     const nftArray=[];
     for (var snap of nft.docs){
       var data = snap.data()
        data.ID = snap.id;
        nftArray.push({
          ...data
        })
        if(nftArray.length===nft.docs.length){
          setNft(nftArray);
        }
      }
    }
    useEffect(()=>{
      getNft();
    })}
        {nft.length > 0 && (
            <div>
                <div className='cardContainer'>
                    <Nft nft={nft}/>
                </div>
            </div>
        )}
        {nft.length < 1 && (
            <div className='loading'>Loading products..</div>
        )}
```

[Infinite loop console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sE9Wl.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

useEffect has a "trigger" property.

ex:

Will run on every render

```
useEffect(() => {
  //do something
});
```

Will run only once

```
useEffect(() => {
  //do something
}, []);
```

Will run when given properties changes

```
useEffect(() => {
  //do something
}, [someProperty, someOtherProperty]);
```

In your case, you are calling the async function, the async function updates the state, and causes a rerender. Since you don't have any trigger (or empty array) added to the useEffect, it will run again, and again, and again.